# Carrierwave to store the full path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to make CarrierWave store, in the database, the full path of the uploaded files instead of just the file name and re-generate them every time they are accessed?

The reason why I want this is to be able to change the structure in which I store files without the already uploaded files disappearing until they are moved to their new locations.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to store the directory on a separate attribute:

```
class MyModel
  before_save do
    self.content_path ||= "uploads/my_model/contents/#{id}"
  end
end
```

Then your uploader will look like this:

```
class YourUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...

  def store_dir
    model.content_path
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your uploader, you have this structure:

```
class YourUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  ...
end
```

I think that if you change `store_dir` to a full path it will do what you want.

Comment: I'm already defining the store_dir like that, the path is not saved to the database, only filename.

Comment: If you save the full path to your database, after you define your new directory structure you will have to update all your files again in your database

Comment: @Octopu-Paul, yeah, moving files and updating them in the database will happen record by record.